# Closing JFrame from JApplet

Tags: java, swing, jframe, japplet

I'm stuck. I have a JFrame that, upon clicking on a JButton, launches a JApplet that is in another JFrame . What I am wondering is how I can close the JFrame in which the JApplet is in upon clicking on an "Exit" JButton in the JApplet.

Edit:I sliced down my code to show what I mean.

```
 import javax.swing.JFrame;

 public class Example {


 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Menu frame = new Menu();
    frame.setTitle("Menu");
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    }
 }
```

.

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Menu extends JFrame{

private JButton jbt=new JButton("Applet");

public Menu(){
    add(jbt);

    ButtonListener listener=new ButtonListener();
    jbt.addActionListener(listener);

}
public static void run(JApplet applet, int width, int height,String title){
    JFrame myFrame = new JFrame();
    myFrame.setTitle(title);
    myFrame.getContentPane().add(applet);
    myFrame.setSize(width, height);
    myFrame.setResizable(true);
    myFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    applet.init();
    applet.start();
    myFrame.setVisible(true);
}

class ButtonListener implements ActionListener{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        if (e.getSource()==jbt)
        {
            run(new myApplet(),400,180,"Applet");
        }

    }
 }
}
```

.

```
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import javax.swing.*;
    public class myApplet extends JApplet{

        private JButton jbtExit=new JButton();

    @Override
    public void init(){
        add(jbtExit);
        jbtExit.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
    }

    class ButtonListener implements ActionListener{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        if (e.getSource()==jbtExit)
        {
            setVisible(false);
        }

    }
 }
```

Comment: Applets are not embedded in a JFrame, they are displayed on a web page. So I don't understand your design or question.

Comment: @camickr Although they aren't meant to be embedded within JFrames, applets *can* be.  After all, there's not much difference (as far as the applet is concerned) whether it's loaded by a web page, or by a frame imitating the functionality of one, but with the applet run on the frame's JVM.

Comment: Sorry what I meant is that the JFrame has a JApplet as content.

Comment: I guess my comment is why would you design something like this? What are you trying to do? Generally you add panels to a frame. Yes a JApplet is just a component by why are you using it instead of a panel?

Comment: I have an assignment where I have to write a java application that displays to the screen a menu. From this menu I must have buttons that call certain applets to display user interfaces.

Comment: I got it to work by adding a [ComponentListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ComponentListener.html) to applet in the run() method of Menu and overriding the componentHidden() method to close the JFrame. Is there a better way?

Comment: I don't understand what a ComponentListener has to do with a JButton. `Is there a better way?` - I gave you a better way 9 hours ago.

Answer (score 1):

See [Closing an Application](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/01/closing-an-application/) for some general ideas.

You should be able to use the `ExitAction` for your Exit button.